# Group Indicator get distorted?

Tags: java, android, listview, expandablelistview

I use a ExpandableListView with a group indicator. The group indicator image should be placed at the right side of the group view and vertically centered without any distortion.

Here is how it looks like:

[image]

The undistorted image looks like this:

[image]
[image]

Here is my layout:

```
<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:groupIndicator="@drawable/list_group_indictor"
    android:divider="@color/whiteColor"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
```

Here is the style `list_group_indictor`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/carat_right" />

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/carat_down"
        android:state_expanded="true" />

</selector>
```

**How do I get the group indicator on the right side, placed in vertical center without being distorted?**

Edit: I tried to generate 9-patch images with [this](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html) tool using content padding. The result is this:

[image]

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Could you please post an example and explain why 9-patch?

Comment: You don't have to set the marker on the padding area. But on the stretch area, as I did with the 9 patches I posted. Or didn't you see my edited answer, yet?

Comment: Could write a few more lines. I do not get how you did this.

Comment: As reported in the tutorial page (by the way, did you read my answer at all?) I linked in my answer, the padding area is where you set the contents (back = content), while the stretch area is where you set what is stretchable (black = stretchable). On the markers border, black must be **black** (#ff000000) all the rest transparent (#00000000). If you'd give my patches a trial, they'd run at the very first attempt. Just name them properly.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **9 patches**, rather than normal pngs.
Just put the top and left markers on empty areas to stretch those portions only (which would result in adding some padding on scaling).

A nice tutorial on 9 patches will make you see why you need to use them, better than my words: http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/

---

**[EDIT]**

These are the patches:

[image]

and

[image]

And this is how they look in the `draw9patch` tool - you can clearly see the 9 patch markers in action:

[image]

and

[image]

You can see the arrow doesn't get stretched, only the transparent part on its perimeter.
Which is the desired effect.

Remember that the extension has to be **.9.png**, not **.png**

Comment: Yes that would be great please prepare one for me.

Comment: ... two. I'll prepare both "down" and "rite".

Comment: Please see my edit I tried to use 9-patch but it gets worse.

Comment: Your 9 patches are **wrong**. Why don't you try mine, instead?